# Winbind installation error

Tags: software-installation

I get this error everytime I install something in Ubuntu 11.10

'E: winbind: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1'

Fortunately the programs still install. How do I fix this problem??

Comment: did you really mean 11.10? yo do know that it's still in **DEVELOPMENT** right?.

Comment: Save issue as:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/66606/fails-to-boot-after-upgrade-stuck-on-winbind-package

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```