# Fails to boot after upgrade, stuck on winbind package

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

I started the upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 last night. Once it got the installing packages part I left the computer unattended the rest of the night. When I checked it this morning the screen was blank and I couldn't get it to turn on. So I cycled power, and now I get the "Ubuntu 11.10" screen with the dots underneath, but then it gets to a blank screen and nothing more. I can get to the command line in recovery mode; here's a list of the things I've tried so far

- `sudo apt-get update` - the very first repository it checked sat at 0% for a long time (network cable is plugged in), so I cancelled with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>
- Thought it might be a problem with display drivers, so I tried `sudo apt-get install nvidia-glx` - this gave me an error saying *dpkg has been interrupted, manually run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`*
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a` this installed / updated a bunch of stuff but got stuck at *Starting Winbind daemon winbind*
- Restarted and tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` again but it gets stuck at same Windbind step

What else can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try `sudo dpkg --purge winbind` to completely remove it first (this package is a part of [samba](http://packages.ubuntu.com/samba) [image: Install samba] which facilitates sharing files over a network with machines running Windows). You can reinstall the package later if you wish.

Comment: Thanks! After purging winbind I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` again and it completed successfully. I was then able to boot into Ubuntu normally.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
sudo dpkg --purge winbind
```

does not resolve whether 'winbind' should be still installed.

Problem may re-occur, if user again installs winbind (used by Samba).